# Get Lat,Long values periodically from a service and update database

Tags: android

My scenario is to get lat and long of the mobile device for every 20sec  and put the lat,long values in database using asmx web service.I have written a service which implements location listener and able to get the lat long values from the service

The implementation of the service is as below.My GpsTracker Service.

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    // Get Class Name
    private static String TAG = GPSTracker.class.getName();

    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS Status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS Tracking is enabled 
    boolean isGPSTrackingEnabled = false;

    Location location;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    // How many Geocoder should return our GPSTracker
    int geocoderMaxResults = 1;

    // The minimum distance to change updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 *20* 1; //5 seconds

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    // Store LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER or LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER information
    private String provider_info;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    /**
     * Try to get my current location by GPS or Network Provider
     */
    public void getLocation() {

        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            //getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            //getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            // Try to get location if you GPS Service is enabled
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                this.isGPSTrackingEnabled = true;

                Log.d(TAG, "Application use GPS Service");

                /*
                 * This provider determines location using
                 * satellites. Depending on conditions, this provider may take a while to return
                 * a location fix.
                 */

                provider_info = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;

            } else if (isNetworkEnabled) { // Try to get location if you Network Service is enabled
                this.isGPSTrackingEnabled = true;

                Log.d(TAG, "Application use Network State to get GPS coordinates");

                /*
                 * This provider determines location based on
                 * availability of cell tower and WiFi access points. Results are retrieved
                 * by means of a network lookup.
                 */
                provider_info = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;

            } 

            // Application can use GPS or Network Provider
            if (!provider_info.isEmpty()) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    provider_info,
                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, 
                    this
                );

                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider_info);
                    updateGPSCoordinates();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "Impossible to connect to LocationManager", e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Update GPSTracker latitude and longitude
     */
    public void updateGPSCoordinates() {
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
    }

    /**
     * GPSTracker latitude getter and setter
     * @return latitude
     */
    public double getLatitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * GPSTracker longitude getter and setter
     * @return
     */
    public double getLongitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * GPSTracker isGPSTrackingEnabled getter.
     * Check GPS/wifi is enabled
     */
    public boolean getIsGPSTrackingEnabled() {

        return this.isGPSTrackingEnabled;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this method will stop using GPS in your app
     */
    public void stopUsingGPS() {
        if (locationManager != null) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        latitude=location.getLatitude();
    longitude=location.getLongitude();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And in my activity I have two buttons upon click of the button this service should be started.But now I am having the following problems

1)If the phone goes to sleep mode the lat,long values are not fetched by the service.

2)How to return the lat,long values to the activity so that I can call a web service which puts the lat,long values in database(a different app picks these values from here)

3)The `LocationManager.requestlocationupdates` function gives lat long values in irregular intervals than what is specified in the arguments

I have seen people using AlarmManager,but i don't get the proper usage as `LocationManager.requestlocationupdates` provides the same functionality.Connecting to asmx part is pretty clear and I am using ksoap jar file for that.Is there any other which is better than that.

I have also tried using CWAC LocationPoller which is an awesome thing,but as Commonware suggested in previous posts that LocationPoller is designed for much longer polling periods: an hour, not 10 seconds.I have dropped on proceeding that idea.

This is my first Service that I have seen and I am complete newbie to android world who has delved into it 3 days ago.Please Help!!.Expecting your valuable suggestions

Thanks in Advance..